# Popup windows that automatically close in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My Selenium Webdriver test is something like:

- Click button -> this opens popup window
- Iterate through all window handles and switch to popup window
- Fill out form on popup window and submit.

At this point, the popup window might automatically close if the input was valid or it will stay open if there is an error on the form.

My question is, if the window automatically closes and that was the window handle I had focus on, what happens exactly? Is there a way for me to detect that the window has closed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the focused window closed, then the `Web Driver` instance had no focus on any window and it throw an exception if you are trying to find any element. It throws `NoSuchElementException` when you trying to find an element. You can check the window presence by counting the number of windows.

Answer (score 0):

The windows handles keeps the record of pop of window even if it closes automatically. So you have to switch to the parent window. And then use the print statement for Windows.title  to check which window is opened.